# Play Scala activator compile command shows value userid is not a member of play.api.data.Form[models.Changepas sword]

Tags: scala, model-view-controller, playframework, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

I am new to play framework(Scala),In my project I need to update new `Password` for this I need to get `user id` which is `Primary key` for that `user table`. Based on this unique `user id` value i will update `Password`.

**What I need**

need to get `user` table's `user id` value and pass this value into Controller's `Action`

**What I tried**

**controllers/users.scala**

```
 import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import views._
import models._


  val changepasswordForm = Form(
          mapping(
            "userid" -> ignored(None:Option[Int]),
              "password" -> tuple(
            "main" -> text,
            "confirm" -> text
          ).verifying(
            // Add an additional constraint: both passwords must match
            "Passwords don't match", passwords => passwords._1 == passwords._2
          ) 
          )(models.Changepassword.apply)(models.Changepassword.unapply)
          )

 def changePassword =   Action {
     Ok(html.changePassword(changepasswordForm))
   }



def updatePassword(userid: Int) = Action { implicit request =>
    changepasswordForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.changePassword(formWithErrors)),
      user => {
        Changepassword.update(userid, user)
    Ok("password Updated")
      }
    )
  }
```

**models/User.scala**

```
case class Changepassword(
     userid: Option[Int] = None,
     password:(String,String)
    )
object Changepassword{

    val simple = {
    get[Option[Int]]("user.USER_ID") ~
    get[String]("user.PASSWORD") map {
      case userid~password => Changepassword(userid, (password,password))
    }
  }
     def update(userid: Int,changepassword:Changepassword) = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("update  user set PASSWORD = {changepassword} where USER_ID = {userid}").
      on('userid -> userid,
          'changepassword -> changepassword.password._1)
      .executeUpdate()
    }
  }
}
```

**views/changePassword.scala.html**

```
@(userForm: Form[Changepassword])

@import helper._

@implicitFieldConstructor = @{ FieldConstructor(twitterBootstrapInput.f) } 

@main("") {

    <h1>Change Password</h1>

    @form(routes.Users.updatePassword(userForm.userid.get)) {

        <fieldset>


            @inputPassword(userForm("password.main"), '_label -> "New Password", '_help -> "",'placeholder -> "New Password")
             @inputPassword(userForm("password.confirm"), '_label -> "Confirm Password", '_help -> "",'placeholder -> "Repeat Password")

        </fieldset>

        <div class="actions">
            <input type="submit" value="Change password" class="btn primary"> or
            <a href="@routes.Application.index()" class="btn">Cancel</a> 
        </div>

    }

}
```

If I run `activator compile` command it shows below exception

```
D:\Jamal\test>activator compile
[info] Loading project definition from D:\Jamal\test\p
roject
[info] Set current project to scala-crud (in build file:/D:\Jamal\test/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to D:\Jamal\test\targe
t\scala-2.11\classes...
[error] D:\Jamal\test\app\views\changePassword.sc
ala.html:11: value userid is not a member of play.api.data.Form[models.Changepas
sword]
[error]     @form(routes.Users.updatePassword(userForm.userid.get)) {
[error]                                                          ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 13 s, completed Jun 11, 2015 3:52:19 PM

D:\Jamal\test>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the value of the form as a parameter for the route:

```
@form(routes.Users.updatePassword(userForm.userid.get))
```

The userid depends on the form and could therefore change. In any case, you would access the userid of the form using `userForm("userid")` and not `userForm.userid` (although it might not be what you want/need).

A better approach for your problem would be to pass a second parameter like this:

#### controllers/users.scala

```
 def changePassword =   Action {
     val userId = ... get the current id ...
     Ok(html.changePassword(changepasswordForm,userId))
   }
```

#### views/changePassword.scala.html

```
@(userForm: Form[Changepassword], userId:Int)
...
...
  @form(routes.Users.updatePassword(userId)) {
   ...
   ...
  }
...
```

This way, you ensure the userId is known when the page is displayed and that a "evil" user can't change the passwords of other users by manipulating the userId.

Comment: I will check and let you know.

Comment: I added like this `@form(routes.Users.updatePassword(userForm("userid"))) {  

}` but it shows `type mismatch;  found   : play.api.data.Field  required: Int`

Comment: that's because the Form does not contain "values" but fields, including a lot of helper functions to display input fields, etc. Have you tried passing it as a second parameter as suggested?

Comment: No,I know the second option as I already used in my project.It will work.but I need to pass values from `Form` whether is it possible or not?

Comment: Alright. I changed my answer. You don't need to pass the userid as a parameter... you can simply access the value from the form.

Comment: your answer is correct. I have some doubt whether shall we pass `form ` vlaue from form to `Action` then update a password like what i tried `routes.Users.updatePassword(userForm.userid.get)` and what you suggested `routes.Users.updatePassword(userForm("userid"))`

Comment: From your previous `Answer` the second approach was correct.Because this `changePassword.scala.html` is empty form,initially it doesn't contain any values.So need to get the `USER_ID` from `DB` then have to update password based on returned `USER_ID`. So revoke your current edit I will accept your answer.

Comment: Ok. I rolled it back.